# Why would ASP.NET Core FileProvider methods return a different timestamp than than the IIS server time settings

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-10

I am using ASP.NET Core FileProvider class to pull the last modified date from a local IIS Server. The IIS server shows eastern standard time when I log in which is correct but when I run my code below it returns a time stamp that is four hours forward. My ASP.NET code is running on a PC that is also US eastern standard time so I am not sure what is causing this four hour difference or if there is a way to ensure these time zone difference do not cause confusion for users on the front end.

```
                    foreach (var file in mainreviewdocuments)
                {

                    file["DATE_LAST_MODIFIED"] = _fileProvider.GetFileInfo(file["DOCUMENT_FULL_PATH"].ToString()).LastModified.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt");
                    
                }

                json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mainreviewdocuments);
```

Comment: What does `Eastern Standard Time` mean? Whose Eastern? The US's? Europe's? China has a single timezone so maybe Russia with 11 time zones? Are you sure the problem isn't caused by `LastModified.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt")` which serializes the binary DateTime value to a US locale without checking if the value is UTC or Local?

Comment: In any case, you didn't demonstrate the actual problem. It's unclear what timestamp you're talking about, what `mainreviewdocuments` is. If you intend to serialize the date to JSON, you introduced a bug - dates in JSON are in ISO8601 format. That's [part of the standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7493#section-4.3), not optional. No other application will be able to read that `json` string or properly deserialize the non-date string.

Comment: My apologies. I meant US Eastern Standard Time.  Mainreviewdocuments is just the list of documents i am looping through to get the last modified date. So converting to a string is probably poor practice and should keep that as a Date variable type? Sorry I will admit I am still relatively new to web development so this I am sure is a novice mistake.

Comment: probably difference between UTC and EST: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#model-binding-changes-in-aspnet-core-mvc-and-razor-pages

Comment: Yea it looks like i needed to add ToLocalTime() function and it corrected the issue.